# How do i close a socket after a timeout in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to close a socket after a connection times out after 1000ms. I am able to set a timeout that gets triggered after a 1000ms but I can't seem to destroy the socket... any ideas?

```
var connection = http.createClient(80, 'localhost');
var request = connection.request('GET', '/somefile.xml', {'host':'localhost'});
var start = new Date().getTime();

request.socket.setTimeout(1000);

request.socket.addListener("timeout", function() {
  request.socket.destroy();
  sys.puts("socket timeout connection closed");
});

request.addListener("response", function(response) {
  var responseBody = [];
  response.setEncoding("utf8");
  response.addListener("data", function(chunk) {
    sys.puts(chunk);
    responseBody.push(chunk);
  });

  response.addListener("end", function() {

  });
});

request.end();
```

returns

```
socket timeout connection closed
node.js:29
  if (!x) throw new Error(msg || "assertion error");
                ^
Error: assertion error
    at node.js:29:17
    at Timer.callback (net:152:20)
    at node.js:204:9
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two way.
The problem is a bug.

1. upgrade node.js to gt 0.3.7
   https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/2ec4cd552501b895c83c6871951c1a6256288c48
2. edit the code
   https://github.com/Hotelsnl/Socket.IO-node/blob/63624e5996b2719bb08f38a8af143c2019617da3/lib/socket.io/client.js

Answer (score 0):

You might get better answers on the IRC channel `#node.js` on freenode. But AFAIK node isn't quite designed for canceling something mid-way. Mostly people just leave it dangling since, in node.js, there's no blocking I/O anyway.

I agree though, that there should be a way to cancel something mid-way, but I don't think you should mess with the request's internal socket connection. That's why you have the `http.ClientRequest` abstraction to manage the socket for you. The error could be because the timeout *does* works but that the request object weren't expecting the socket to already be closed.

Hope this helps.